# jquery datatables set column to not order

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Here is my jquery datatable code:

```
    var tbl = jq('#datatablecontents').dataTable({
      "paging":   false,        
      "info":     false,
      "searching": false,
      "scrollCollapse" : false                      
    });
    jq(orderDatatableContents).each(function(index, value) {
      tbl.column(index+':visible').order('asc');
    });
```

I also tried:

```
     jq('#datatablecontents').dataTable({
        "paging":   false,        
        "info":     false,
        "searching": false,
        "scrollCollapse" : false  ,
        "order" : orderDatatableContents
    });
```

`orderDatatableContents` is a multidimensional array containing 4 out of 5 columns. The documentation for that is here: [click here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order())

Basically i'd like to have every column but the last column to have sorting.

**How do I negate a column from being sortable?**

Comment: Use `bSortable` property and set it to `false`.

Comment: @D4V1D can you elaborate? I tried that and it didnt work

Comment: What version of `dataTable` are you using?

Comment: @D4V1D Version 1.10.5

Comment: `bSortable` is for previous versions of `dataTables`. The new property is called `orderable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [`orderable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) property and set it to `false` like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   var tbl = jq('#datatablecontents').dataTable({
       "paging":   false,        
       "info":     false,
       "searching": false,
       "scrollCollapse" : false,
       "columnDefs": [ // you will have to set an array of object representing each column
           {"orderable": false, "targets": 0},
           {"orderable": true, "targets": 1},
           // and so on
       ]                    
   });

});
```

Comment: columnDefs requires `target` property

Comment: My columns array currently has arrays in the following format: `var tmpStk = [index,'asc'];`

Comment: Right so tmpStk is an array containing the column index and the order mode. i push all of the columns i need to sort into an array and pass that into `orderDatatableContents` as defined in the question

Comment: How this prevents you from using the solution I provided you with?

Comment: Glad it works. I've edited my answer. Feel free to also upvote it. Happy coding! :)